# What is the difference between 'a and ''a in SML?

Tags: polymorphism, sml, ml

For example:

```
fun example (a:'a list) : list = a
```

will have a signatures of:

```
'a list -> 'a list
```

What if I define it differently but with same content like

```
fun example (a : ''a list) : list = a
```

its signature will be:

```
''a list -> ''a list
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A plain type variable like `'a` can be substituted with an arbitrary type. The form `''a` is a so-called *equality type* variable, which means that it can only be substituted by types that admit the use of the equality operator `=` (or `<>`) on their values.

For example, this function:

```
fun contains(x, [])    = false
  | contains(x, y::ys) = x = y orelse contains (x, ys)
```

cannot have type `'a * 'a list -> bool` because it uses equality on `x`. It is given the more restrictive type `''a * ''a list -> bool`.

Most types allow equality, but some don't, e.g., `real`, `exn`, and in particular, any function type `t -> u`. Composed types like records, tuples, or datatypes admit equality if all their components do.

Side remark: Haskell later generalised this concept to its notion of *type classes*, which allows arbitrary user-defined constraints of this sort on types. Equality type variables are replaced by the `Eq` type class.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot. I'm right now taking a course in standard ML NJ. I only had some python experience before.  Why real type can't use equality operator?

Comment: Equality on floating points, as defined by IEEE, is not an equivalence relation (because of its behaviour on NaNs and -0). It would hence break all sorts of properties of the generic equality operator. If you really need IEEE equality, it is available as `Real.==`. (However, using equality on floats is a bad idea in practice, due to the imprecision of float computation.)

Comment: @Wei Wang: additionally to Andrea's answer, you may look at the SML's `eqtype` keyword, which may be used in signatures. It's purpose is to assert such an annotated type appearing in a signature, is an *equality type* as explained by Andrea.