# What is error of unresolved flex record in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am new to SML, and have asked people about the error that I got. But, I can't find where the problem is.

The error message is received is:

```
stdIn:10.1-16.48 Error: unresolved flex record (need to know the names       
of ALL  the fields in this context)
type: {1:''Y, 2:''X; ''Z}
```

I have two functions. The first function is reverse, which is to reverse a list and return it. For example, reversing [1,2,3,4] to [4,3,2,1]. This function has absolutely no problems.

```
fun reverse(L) =
   if L = nil then nil
   else reverse(tl(L)) @ [hd(L)];
```

The next function is getDirectNode, which takes 3 parameters, starting node, list of tuples containing edges, and an empty list. For example, I have a node, 1, for the first argument. I have a list of tuples containing all edges. [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4)], for the second argument. Lastly, the third argument will be an empty list.

In the getDirectNodes function, it will find the tuples that has 1 as its first number. In this case, it will get (1,2) and (1,3). Then, it will put 2 and 3 into the empty list and return it. So, the function will return the [2,3].

Here is my function:

```
  fun getDirectNodes(startNode,Tuples,list) =
     if Tuples = [] 
        then list
     else if #1(hd(Tuples)) = startNode
        then getDirectNodes(startNode,tl(Tuples),reverse(#2(hd(Tuples)) :: list))
     else
        getDirectNodes(startNode, tl(Tuples),list)
```

What can be possibly causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is caused by the SML compiler not being able to infer what type of tuple you have. `#1` and `#2` are not functions but macros that work on tuples of arbitrary type, as long as they have two elements. So a quick way to overcome this problem is to add type annotation,

```
fun getDirectNodes(startNode, Tuples : (int * int) list, list) = ...
```

But since you posted so much of your solution, I'd like to give some general feedback on it:

### reverse

Your implementation of `reverse` does a few things wrong:

1. When you write `if L = [] ...`, you force `L` to be an [equality type, `''a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437520/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-a-in-sml). This may seem odd, since you're just testing that `L` is empty, but before `L = []` can be a valid expression, its elements must also be comparable for equality. You can solve this via pattern matching or by using the function `List.null` (which uses pattern matching) to avoid the equality type restriction.
2. It uses `hd` and `tl` instead of pattern matching; these functions are [partial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions), which means they can crash at run-time when not used properly. You can avoid them by using pattern matching on the empty and the non-empty list.
3. It uses `@` recursively which is *very* inefficient: Your algorithm is *O(n²)* because the left-hand side of `@` takes linear time to resolve for each recursive call, i.e. geometric complexity:

   ```
      reverse [1,2,3,4]
   ~> reverse [2,3,4] @ [1]
   ~> reverse [3,4] @ [2] @ [1]
   ~> reverse [4] @ [3] @ [2] @ [1]
   ~> reverse [] @ [4] @ [3] @ [2] @ [1]
   ```

   At this point `reverse` has used *O(n)* stack space.

   ```
   ~> [] @ [4] @ [3] @ [2] @ [1]
   ~> [4] @ [3] @ [2] @ [1]       (* 1 recursive call in @ *)
   ~> [4,3] @ [2] @ [1]           (* 2 recursive calls in @ *)
   ~> [4,3,2] @ [1]               (* 3 recursive calls in @ *)
   ~> [4,3,2,1]                   (* 4 recursive calls in @ *)
   ```

   And at this point `reverse` has used *O(n + (n-1) + ... + 1) = O(n²)* recursive calls.
4. There's actually a built-in function called `rev`.

   It is implemented like this:

   ```
   fun rev xs =
     let fun rev_helper []      xs_bw = xs_bw
           | rev_helper (x::xs) xs_bw = rev_helper xs (x::xs_bw)
     in rev_helper xs [] end
   ```

   and calling it looks like:

   ```
      rev [1,2,3,4]
   ~> rev_helper [1,2,3,4] []
   ~> rev_helper [2,3,4] [1]   (* 1 recursive call *)
   ~> rev_helper [3,4] [2,1]   (* 1 recursive call *)
   ~> rev_helper [4] [3,2,1]   (* 1 recursive call *)
   ~> rev_helper [] [4,3,2,1]  (* 1 recursive call *)
   ~> [4,3,2,1]
   ```

   which uses *heap* memory instead of *stack* memory, and *O(n)* recursive calls.

### getDirectNodes

Here is a non-exhaustive list of comments:

1. The same thing wrt. equality types applies here wrt. `Tuples = []`.
2. Having `list` as an accumulated result is neat! I might have called it something more descriptive, just as I would call `Tuples` something like `edges` to describe its *content* rather than its *type*.
3. While using an accumulated result like `list` is neat, it means that your function takes as input an empty list. What if the caller feeds it a non-empty list? Exposing this extra argument leaves room for errors, so hide it in an inner function, like I did with `rev_helper`.
4. Use pattern matching instead of `hd` and `tl`.
5. Your use of `reverse` seems meaningful: You've experienced that `list` ends up in reverse. But instead of calling `reverse` on `list` on every recursive call, do it *once* at the very end (when `Tuples` is empty).

Given this advice, here is a variation of your code:

```
fun getDirectNodes (startNode, []) = []
  | getDirectNodes (startNode, (x, endNode) :: edges) =
    if x = startNode
    then endNode :: getDirectNodes (startNode, edges)
    else getDirectNodes (startNode, edges)
```

And a variation that uses an inner tail-recursive function and a single `rev` at the end:

```
fun getDirectNodes (startNode, edges) =
    let fun helper ([], endNodes) = endNodes
          | helper ((x, endNode) :: edges, endNodes) =
            if x = startNode
            then helper (edges, endNode :: endNodes)
            else helper (edges, endNodes)
    in rev (helper (edges, [])) end
```

Here is how I would make it using higher-order functions:

```
fun getDirectNodes (startNode, edges) =
    List.map #2 (List.filter (fn (x, _) => x = startNode) edges)
```

The reason I don't get a warning wrt. my use of `#2` here, in spite of not having any type annotations, is because I'm pattern matching on the elements of `edges` in the code `fn (x, _) => ...`. This constrains `edges` to a list of 2-tuples.

Running this:

```
- getDirectNodes (1, [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4)]);
> val it = [2, 3] : int list
```